# Grid typesetting

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids, grid-typesetting

**Question**

Is there any way to manage that text stays on the grid given by a tikzpicture?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

  \tikzset{normal lines/.style={black!20, very thin}} 
  \tikzset{margin lines/.style={black!20, thick}} 

  \node at (current page.south west){
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

      \draw[style=normal lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid +(210mm,297mm); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\blindtext[2]

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\blindtext[3]

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not really, since you have a variety of box heights when looking at the horizontal lines as boxes that fill up the text block. For example, the `\baselineskip` of the sections (and surrounding spaces) are not the same as that of the paragraph text.

Comment: So the only solution is to MANUALLY shift headings, adapt spacing of paragaphs etc.?

Comment: I guess you'll have to ensure that the content conforms to a "`\baselineskip` interval." If you have only regular/paragraph text, this should be okay, but as soon as you add sectional units and floats, then things might not line up as expected. Two alternatives are possible: (1) [Use LuaLaTeX to "process the input buffer" before content is set on the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289732/5764); (2) Change [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18760/5764) to put in horizontal rules rather than line numbers after the document is already created.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401778/setting-titles-to-be-a-multiple-of-baselineskip-fo-grid-typesetting

Comment: If off-grid is ONLY caused by things such as section headings, try:: (1) Do not use automated sections. Instead, manually create them using (styled) text. (2) Enclose section headings in 
 `\smash{}` which nullifies increased line height due to larger text. The enclosed text will not wrap, but you can break it into several lines, each with their own `\smash{}`. (3) Use `\null` before and after the section heading, to space an integer number of lines. (4) If your work is more like a novel than like an academic report, the `novel` document class has grid typesetting built in. Cannot use TiKz.

Comment: @RobtAll why not just set the space used by the standard headings rather that use manually styled text?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Certainly that works. But I tend to favor brute force approaches that can be used under other circumstances. I can type and count to ten, but I can only count to five while typing, due to limited fingers.

Comment: @RobtAll not always possible but a basic premise of latex is that as far as possible you separate the document markup (sections marked with `\section`) from details of layout implementation, so even if you define all the macros "by hand" it is best to call the resulting macro `\section` and keep the resulting document markup basically unchanged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not entirely trivial to get it to work for all input as TeX really wants to use stretchy glue to align things and that will always take you off grid, but basically you just need to ensure that any spaces added are multiples of your grid unit (I took .5cm here) so in this case I forced baselineskip, topskip, and the space before and after section headings to fit this grid

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      remember picture, 
      overlay,
      normal lines/.style={black!20, very thin},
    ]
    \draw [style=normal lines, step=0.5cm]  (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east); 
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-1cm}%
  {1cm}%
  {\normalfont\Large\baselineskip.5cm\relax\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\lineskip0pt
\baselineskip.5cm
\normalbaselineskip=\baselineskip
\topskip\baselineskip

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\blindtext[2]

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\blindtext[3]

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tikzpicture` environments ought not be nested. Doing so is unsupported. It may happen to work or it may not. But, sooner or later, it will probably break in mysterious ways.

Comment: `overlay` inside `overlay` seems especially strange.

Comment: Roll back if you object to my edit. (I only changed the Ti*k*Z code to be passably sane.)

Comment: @cfr I never realised that it was possible to have passably sane tikz code:-)

Comment: Everything's relative. Except what is absolute.

Comment: Will this work with math formulas within the text?

Comment: @JPMD best not to ask questions as comment on old answers, but in principle yes, so long as you set the correct lengths eg `\abovedisplayskip`

Comment: Thanks @David... can you give an example on how to use `\abovedisplayskip`?

Comment: @JPMD https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cabovedisplayskip