# How to align lines in a two-column layout?

Tags: spacing, plain-tex

I am trying to use a two-column layout in plain TeX (pdftex, to be precise), where the lines of text in the two columns are vertically aligned.  Here is what I've got so far (code is below):

[image: example of the (broken) two-column layout]

Normal rows should take up 12pt of vertical space, headings (A and B) should take up 36 points when they are in the middle of a column, or 24 points when they are at the top of a column.  My aim is for lines on the left and on the right to have the same vertical position, like line 1a and 7g currently do.

My questions:

1. Section heading A consists of a `vskip` of 12pt, followed by a `vbox` of height 24pt.  I hoped that it would take up the same space as three rows do.  The picture shows, that the heading takes up slightly too much space, pushing line 6f down a bit.  How can I make the section heading A take up exactly three rows of space?
2. For heading B I had hoped that the `vskip` is discarded (because of the page break), leaving only the `vbox` of height 24pt.  The picture shows that heading B takes up much more than 2 rows of vertical space.  How can I remove the extra space so that rows 15o and 21u align vertically?

Here is my code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdftex

% tiny pages for testing
\pdfpageheight 92pt\voffset -62.27pt\vsize72pt
\pdfpagewidth 120pt\hoffset -62.27pt\hsize50pt
\parindent0pt\parskip0pt\topskip0pt

% a very simple two-column layout
\newbox\leftcol
\newif\ifleftcol\leftcoltrue
\def\xout{\ifleftcol
\global\setbox\leftcol\box255
\global\leftcolfalse
\else
\shipout\vbox to 72pt{\hbox to 100pt{\box\leftcol \box255}}%
\global\leftcoltrue
\fi}
\output{\xout}

% section headings (2 lines on top of column, 3 line otherwise)
\font\bigfont=ecbx2488
\def\section#1{\vskip1\baselineskip\vbox to24pt{\vss\noindent\bigfont#1}}

% visually mark the baselines for testing
\everypar{\hbox to0pt{\vrule height.1pt depth.1pt width50pt\hss}}
\obeylines

1a
2b
\section{A}
6f
7g
8h
9i
10j
11k
12l
\section{B}
15o
16p
17q
18r
19s
20t
21u
22v
23w
24x

\bye
```

Comment: In my experiment, changing `\pdfpageheight 92pt\voffset -62.27pt\vsize72pt` to `\pdfpageheight132pt\voffset -62.27pt\vsize120pt` leads to unexpected result: The baselines are not aligned at all! Note even one pair of them!

Comment: The paracol package comes to mind, but I'm not if the baselines or tops are aligned when switching columns (which can only be done between paragraphs).  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401778/setting-titles-to-be-a-multiple-of-baselineskip-fo-grid-typesetting/401799?s=2|11.2503#401799

Comment: @RuixiZhang Thanks for pointing this out.  Experimenting a bit more, it seems that my `\topskip0pt` was a bad idea.  Changing this to `\topskip10pt` makes the first lines of your larger pages align properly.  Things are still out of alignment after the headings, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general advice:

When you stack boxes be careful with occurrences of `\lineskip`. Use
`\nointerlineskip` or `\offinterlineskip` and apply a `\strut` to know the height
and depth of lines.

The details for your example:

1) `\topskip` is used to have first lines at the same position. TeX calculates
   the width (topskip - height of first line) and put this difference as glue
   at the beginning of the page.
   So `\topskip=0pt` means that the baselines of a line with 'a' and a
   line with 'h' have different distances from the top of the print area. This
   is not what you want.

2) `\topskip=10pt` is sufficient for cmr10. The `\vsize` shall be set then
   as (number of lines - 1)baselineskip + topskip.
   Here `\topskip=\baselineskip` is useful for box B on the second page.

Therefore set `\topskip=12pt` and keep `\vsize=72pt`.

3) Similar to the process in 1) the glue needed between lines is calculated
   from the depth of one line and the height of the next to get the distance
   `\baselineskip`. This glue is called interline glue.
   If the interline glue gets smaller than `\lineskiplimit` TeX sets `\lineskip`
   glue between the lines.
   The boxes of the big letters are larger than `\baselineskip` so `\lineskip` is applied.
   It is set to 1pt and that makes the lines for A and 6f 1pt lower than the lines
   on the right side.
   (Use `\tracingoutput=1` and `\showboxdepth=100`, `\showboxbreadth=100` to see the page
   contents and search for `\lineskip`.)

Therefore use `\nointerlineskip` in the definition of your `\section`.

4) Your rules add the depth 0.1pt. So the section for A changes the baseline by a
   little bit more than 36pt after 2b. The `\vskip` does not care about the depth
   of the previous line.
   (Better use a `\strut` in the line then you know its depth, i.e., all lines have
   the same depth; the `\vskip` can be changed so that exactly `\baselineskip` is
   left above the box.)

Therefore instead of `\vskip1\baselineskip` use `\vskip11.9pt` in this example for a
perfect alignment after a line with depth zero.

This fixes both pages with your input:

```
\topskip12pt
\def\section#1{\vskip11.9pt\nointerlineskip
   \vbox to24pt{\vss\noindent\bigfont#1}}
```